# Full width div inside container and flexed row

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements inside bootstrap row of container. I need to position the elements in such a way that first element remains full viewport width and other 2 remains side by side inside container width. The first element is in absolute position beacuse it will be used as background of the conatiner. How can i achive that?

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 slider-content"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 text-end slider-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the styles

```
#particles-js{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can i do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you question clearly but do you mean something like this?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 slider-content"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6 text-end slider-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and do

```css
#particles-js{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-container{
  display:flex;
}

.slider-content{
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Still its inside container `https://dgarma.com`